# Basic web server written in C, with PHP support

Tags: php, c, sockets, cgi, fastcgi

I'd like to build a basic web server for practicing purposes in C. I understand the basics of it, like opening a socket, and spitting back response based on the request. The problem is that how should I process the PHP scripts. I couldn't find anything useful, for example how to communicate with PHP-FPM the right way. Only thing I could find I out is how to do it directly from terminal.

```
SCRIPT_NAME=/a.php \
SCRIPT_FILENAME=/a.php \
REQUEST_METHOD=GET \
cgi-fcgi -bind -connect 127.0.0.1:9000
```

I know I should somehow pass the required data to through the socket, but I have no idea how. Every help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

in general:

1. the client requests a web page by passing that web page path/name to the server.  The web page should end in `php`
2. the server receives a request for a `php` web page. (to the server, this is just a file name.
3. the server invokes `php`, passing it the web page
4. `php` processes the web page and outputs the result
5. the server passes those results back to the client
6. the client handles the results received from the server.

Comment: I understand this part, my question is about the exact communication with FPM, for example how can I tell it which PHP file should be executed.